# Como posso simplificar os URLs para um site?

Tags: apache, htaccess, url, url-rewrite

Para aceder a uma área em particular do site, tenho que indicar de um a três parâmetros no URL:

**URL normal:**

```
# aceder a um módulo
http://www.meusite.com/index.php?mod=john

# aceder a um sub-módulo:
http://www.meusite.com/index.php?mod=john&call=doe

# Aceder a um conteúdo específico no sub-módulo:
http://www.meusite.com/index.php?mod=john&call=doe&id=1
```

Através do htaccess, estou a tentar permitir acesso aos módulos, sub-módulos e conteúdos específicos da seguinte forma:

```
# aceder a um módulo
http://www.meusite.com/john

# aceder a um sub-módulo:
http://www.meusite.com/john/doe

# aceder a um conteúdo específico no sub-módulo:
http://www.meusite.com/john/doe/1
```

**Até ao momento tenho o seguinte:**

O código em baixo permite-me aceder ao módulo, mas tenho que o repetir por cada módulo existente, faltando ainda lidar com sub-módulos e conteúdos específicos:

```htaccess
# Rewrite the url
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond $0 ^john/
  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?mod=john [NC,L]

  RewriteCond $0 ^jane/
  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?mod=jane [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

## Pergunta

Como é que consigo através do `.htaccess` ler os endereços para que possam ser utilizados de ambas as maneiras em cima apresentadas tendo em conta os três possíveis parâmetros?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Método 1: PHP

Veja um exemplo comentado:

```htaccess
# Se o mod_rewrite estiver ativo
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Ativa a reescrita
RewriteEngine On

# Manuseia as requisições...
 # se a URL não descreve um arquivo ou diretorio existeste
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 # Então sera redirecionado para index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Após usar esse arquivo .htaccess você pode acessar a URL que o usuário solicitou usando a variável `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

```php
<?
   $url = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   $i = 0;
   foreach($url as $u){
       if($i == 0)
           $module = $u;
       elseif($i == 1)
           $subModule = $u;
       elseif($i % 2 == 0)
           $paramName[] = $u;
       else
           $param[] = $u;
   }

   require_once($module . '/' . $submodule . '.php');
```

Não entendi muito bem como vai ser sua estrutura de módulos e submódulos, mais a partir desse código você consegue tratar para incluir o arquivo corretamente e ainda receber todos os parâmetros.

## Método 2: .htaccess (mod_rewrite)

Você pode usar os parâmetros da seguinte forma:

```htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)/([^/]+)
RewriteRule .* http://site.com/index.php?modulo=%1&usuario=%2  [L]
```

Ou Ainda de forma mais elegante

```htaccess
// Quando apenas um parametro for passado
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?modulo=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?modulo=$1

// Quando houver um segundo
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?modulo=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?modulo=$1&id=$2

.
.
.
```

Comment: Nesse novo método, também será possível lidar com a parte do contudo especifico como o exemplo: `http://www.meusite.com/john/doe/1`

Comment: Sim @Zuul, apenas modificando a linha RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)/([^/]+) para pegar tal padrão.

Comment: Ainda Assim, o primeiro método é mais seguro, mesmo que o código que trata o REQUEST_URI esteja um pouco confuso

Answer (score 8):

Pelo que entendi você está tentando tratar todas as regras no .htaccess, acho isso difícil pois no seu exemplo parece que trabalhará com módulos e submódulos, mas isso não é uma regra rígida, algumas vezes somente com módulos.

O ideal seria tratar o .htaccess redirecionando para o index.php, como já descrito na resposta do hernandes. Porém, lembre-se que terá que passar ações e parâmetros também pela url.

Uma forma de ajudar na produtividade e também garantir a qualidade seria utilizar um framework que já tenha os processos de roteamento bem estabelecidos e lhe possibilitem focar no desenvolvimento das regras de negócio de seu sistema, e não na infraestrutura.

Uma sugestão é utilizar um microframework, algumas opções são:

- Lumen: https://lumen.laravel.com/ - baseado no Laravel
- Silex: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/ - baseado no Symfony

Comment: Dei voteup pois concordo plenamente, um framework na verdade é a melhor opção...

Comment: Desnecessário o seu vote down, não é uma resposta que leva à um conceito ou aplicação errôneos. Mas sim uma resposta que irá ajudar no problema de roteamento que ele está tentando resolver, pois como eu disse na resposta, a solução proposta não levava em consideração o mapeamento da ação a ser executada e dos parâmetros a serem tratados.

Answer (score 5):

Recomendo a utilização de Routers para trabalhar com simplificação de urls.

Segue um exemplo criado por brasileiros https://github.com/Respect/Rest

Lá tem um router bem fácil de ser utilizado.