# Preciso gerar páginas separadas para cada anúncio ter uma URL sem parâmetros?

Tags: php, url

Estou a desenvolver um site de classificados. Para cada registo na base de dados é necessário gerar uma página para o anúncio em questão, como nos sites de classificados normais.

Eu fiz uma página genérica que se recebesse um id, por parâmetro no url, imprimia os dados armazenados do anúncio de uma forma estruturada. Mas ao invés de um link como eu tenho, do gênero `/anuncio.php?id=1` eu vejo que outros sites têm algo do gênero `/1.php`,
ou seja, aparentemente têm uma pagina guardada para cada anúncio.

É isso mesmo? Como posso gerar essas páginas individuais, ou fazer com que meus URLs funcionem como nos sites que mecionei?

Comment: Qual é o servidor web utilizado? Apache?

Comment: sim uso o apache mas estou a utilizar servidor local através do xampp

Comment: O XAMPP também usa Apache, então dá na mesma :) Você vai encontrar a resposta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326/como-posso-simplificar-os-urls-para-um-site?rq=1

Comment: Em resumo, não precisa gerar uma página (física, em disco) por anúncio, basta usar o módulo de reescrita de URL do Apache. O link que passei explica como.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda