# Reescrever URL´s usando .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url, url-rewrite, url-amigavel

Como faço para reescrever as seguintes URL´s usando .htaccess

> test.com.br/?section=contact

para

> test.com.br/contact

e

> test.com.br/?section=vehicle&sub=radio

para

> test.com.br/vehicle/radio

Comment: Chegou a pesquisar aqui no SOpt? Tem esta bem boa: [Como posso simplificar os URLs para um site?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1326/201)