# Como faço url amigável no PHP

Tags: php, url, url-amigável

Sei que já perguntaram antes e tem várias respostas na internet mas nenhuma resolveu meu problema.
Tenho um site inteiro em php, com várias  páginas e gostaria de fazer url amigável para as variáveis delas.
Queria, por exemplo, deixar index.php ser apenas /index e profile.php?id=2 virar profile/2.
Devo unir todas as páginas antes de fazer o URL amigável ou dá para fazer assim mesmo?

Desde já obrigado

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326/como-posso-simplificar-os-urls-para-um-site

Comment: Consegui acessar o htacess e formular as variáveis, mas as imagens quebram, nao tem stylesheet. Usei o código:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fight/battle/(.*) fight.php?battle=$1
RewriteRule ^citizen/profile/(.*) profile.php?id=$1

Comment: leia os links relacionados e entenderá porque css e js nao estão carregando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, crie um arquivo .htaccess e ponha o seguinte:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^profile(|/)$ profile.php
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1
```

Not: você precisará, na página "profile" alterar os arquivos pra css, imagem e etc se estiverem, por exemplo, no seguinte formato

> src="/estilos.css"

Deverá alterar para

> src="../estilos.css"

Comment: Eu fiz isso, você diz trocar a stylesheet para .stylesheet no header? E outra, quando eu acesso um link dessa página, ele entra em /profile/5/index.php, por exemplo

Comment: Quando você põe o código em seu htacces, ele meio que "transforma" o arquivo profile em um pasta. Logo, você deve sair da pasta com os links. Então, antes de todos os links, você deve colocar "../" (dois pontos e barra). Exemplo: se o link estiver a href="index" ele deve ficar a href="../index"

Comment: Então o <? require_once('file.php'); ?> vira '../file.php' ?

Comment: Fica sim.  Assim como outros links. Mas isso, apenas na parte do profile

Comment: Ajudou bastante, Obrigado. Eu uso uma página geral para tudo, para organizar apenas o conteúdo na profile, então coloquei uma variável $diretório com o link do site (=http://meusite.com.br/) e usei ela em vez do ../ 
Ta resolvendo. Obrigado

Comment: Feliz em ter ajudado. Sucesso com o site

Comment: Muito Obrigado, sucesso a vida