# URL alternativa em PHP

Tags: php, htaccess

estou com uma dificuldade em criar uma URL alternativa, mais amigável para meus clientes.

O sistema imobiliário que tenho gera um endereço alternativo para cada um deles, exemplo: `http://foo.bar/site.php?id=1042`

Porém, preciso que a URL seja mais amigável, ou seja, simples para ser memorizada. Pensando nisso gerei no sistema a criação de URL para os clientes do tipo `http://foo.bar/gladisonimoveis`

Mas neste caso, o que gostaria é que quando digitassem `http://foo.bar/gladisonimoveis` fosse direcionado para `http://foo.bar/site.php?id=1042` só que dá erro 404, pois não existe um diretório **/gladisonimoveis** só que criar um diretório para cada cliente é algo muito exaustivo.

Um programador colega meu disse que eu posso padronizar isso configurando uma vez no htaccess.

Aguardo ajuda, por favor. Rss

Comment: Existe um recurso chamado `routing` onde você apresenta URLs amigáveis para o usuário e elas são redirecionadas para controllers específicos na sua aplicação, geralmente esse recurso está disponível em frameworks MVC. Você pode pesquisar por `PHP routing` e ver como implementar isso manualmente se for o seu caso.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior vou fazer uma pesquisa sim, obrigado!

Comment: Dá para fazer isso com htaccess sim. Você trabalha com slug no projeto? Não da para passar gladisonimoveis e saber que ele é o id 1042, da para vc passar o gladisonimoveis e pesquisar por quem tem esse slug, ou então passar o id depois do slug, ficaria gladisonimoveis/1042, mas seria melhor passar esse id criptografado.

Answer (score 3):

Crie um arquivo com o nome de *.htaccess* e coloque na raíz do site.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +MultiViews

#pagina de errro
ErrorDocument 404  /404.php  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Crie uma condição para separar as strings da URL e coloque no header do site. (Ou no local adequeado)

Exemplo:

```
//Obtem a URL
$aux = substr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen('/')); 
if( substr( $aux, -1) == '/'){ 
  $aux=substr( $aux, 0, -1); 
} 

//Separa a URL
$urlARRAY___ =explode( '/', $aux); 

$id  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $urlARRAY___[2]);
```

substitua

```
http://foo.bar/site.php?id=1042
```

por

```
http://foo.bar/site/1042
```

Comment: Fiz exatamente como colocado aqui, mas sem sucesso!

Comment: Só utilizando o arquivo .htaccess e colocado a URL manualmente no browser como indicado já deveria funcionar. A segunda parte é para fazer as requisições da base,  e fica difícil de explicar sem saber a estrutura do sistema. Tente utilizar este outro exemplo do SO http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112332/como-fa%C3%A7o-url-amig%C3%A1vel-no-php

Comment: O que eu tenho é um mysql com 3 campos: id, urllonga, urlcurta. Preciso de que quando eu digitar a urlcurta: http://www.roteirodoimovel.com.br/gladisonimoveis redirecionar para a url longa: http://www.roteirodoimovel.com.br/site.php?id=1042. Mas tudo isso dinamicamente, sem eu precisar ficar alterando arquivos a cada cliente novo que entrar no sistema

Comment: Com as instruções passadas, deve-se ignorar urlcurta e urlonga. Faça dinamicamente no .htaccess como explicado.

Answer (score -1):

Dê uma olhada neste seguinte material:

[Criando um mini-framework PHP 5 com MVC](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj86o-9943LAhWDC5AKHc0yCB4QtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F17718083&usg=AFQjCNFzYknWDQFZ1idcE1NxMVtpcTJ7kw&sig2=86I7NraBGzS-5Y1JeCQ6EA)

Créditos a Matheus Moura.

Neste vídeo é explicado o acesso a URL por meio do método `GET`, além da sua formatação através do uso de controllers e actions. Nas demais aulas, é focado a criação de um framework principalmente para o acesso ao banco de dados por meio do `PDO`.

Comment: Leandro, embora o link possa responder a pergunta, é recomendavel que se contextualize o conteudo contido nele, para que o link sirva de apenas referencia para a resposta.

Comment: Ok, Diego, reconheço que foi um pouco mal respondida, vou alterá-la.

Comment: Ensinar a construir uma framework é bom para aprender, mas é reinventar a roda. Há várias frameworks no mercado que já fazem isso há anos, como Symfony (https://symfony.com/) por exemplo.

Comment: Não discordo que é reinventar a roda, é que frameworks são completos, e ele só precisa de um sistema de url amigável, é como se fosse para um desenvolvedor web, o netbeans é mais que completo, porém o sublime tem tudo o que você precisa, é que como eu forneci a primeira aula de um série, também destaquei o que tinha no restante da série