# Como reescrever uma URL?

Tags: htaccess

Olá, quero reescrever uma URL e sei que precisa ser por `.htaccess`.

Tenho essa `URL`:  `www.nomedomeusite.com/visualizar?id=8`

A minha página `visualizar.php` logo no inicio do `body` pega esse `id` e faz uma consulta no meu banco de dados para pegar o resto das informações, deste modo:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT 'nome-da-empresa', 'logo', 'descricao' FROM 'cadastro' WHERE 'id' = $id"
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para reescrever minha `URL`, para que atinja essa forma:

`www.nomedomeusite.com/empresas/nome-da-empresa`

Preciso de uma explicação bem detalhada sobre cada termo usado e cada variavel usada para fazer isso, porque não tenho nenhum conhecimento sobre a programação envolvida no `.htaccess`

Comment: É um site feito só por html e php mesmo, sem nenhum framework

Comment: Essa página `visualizar.php` é uma das paginas comum do meu site, nela eu faço uma chamada de vários elementos do meu banco de dados e exibo eles na tela

Comment: Já leste este post [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326/como-posso-simplificar-os-urls-para-um-site) ?

Comment: Sim, cheguei a ver esse post, mas não consegui entender muito bem aquele código, aí não consegui fazer isso. Se tu pudesse realmente me explicar como posso fazer isso do id, que pega o nome do banco de dados e coloca na url, seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: Essa pergunta na verdade já existe, e também já foi respondida, mas o facto desta ter recompensa, não permite que seja marcada como duplicada. Mas para todo o caso, seria algo como, ao clicar no `link` de um artigo *(o próprio link seria o título do artigo)*, abriria uma página específica que mostraria o conteúdo desse artigo, é isso ?

Comment: Para isso vais ter de esperar, porque de momento estou algo condicionado fisicamente, a menos que alguém faça o favor de dar essa resposta antes de mim. Caso ninguém responda, *provavelmente* até amanhã ao final do dia passo a resposta.

Comment: Ok, estou tentando algumas coisas aqui, usando aquele post lá que tu mencionou, qualquer coisa, se eu achar resposta eu aviso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicolas você pode usar a seguinte regra no seu .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# informa que será aplicada uma condicao no arquivo solicitado 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$

#cria a condicao
RewriteRule ^empresa/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /visualizar.php?nome=$1 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Já no seu arquivo ***visualizar.php***  você terá que fazer algumas modificações, como por exemplo, alterar a sua busca no banco, ao invés de procurar pelo id você vai procurar pelo nome da empresa.

```
$id = $_GET['nome'];
$sql = "SELECT 'nome-da-empresa', 'logo', 'descricao' FROM 'cadastro' WHERE 'nome-da-empresa' = $id"
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado por responder. Eu fiz as devidas mudanças pra fazer a busca por nome. Mas a minha dúvida, é se eu tenho que mudar o href dos artigos de: `visualizar.php?nome=$nome` para `empresas/$nome`. Porque se eu não coloco esse último `href` expressamente, a URL não muda. Porém, ao colocar esse href, abre uma página toda em branco, sem os css e nem as imagens que a `visualizar.php` tinha. Como resolver?

Comment: Nicolas você deverá mudar todas as chamadas para seusite.com.br/empresas/nome-da-empresa ele sozinho nao irá redirecionar as chamadas na url antiga. Quanto aos seus arquivos css e js você pode usar o console do google chrome pra ver qual é o caminho que está sendo chamado para seus assets e alterá-los ou até mesmo criar uma nova regra no seu .htaccess para evitar que os arquivos não sejam encontrados devido a url amigável.

Answer (score 2):

Para o teu caso, a solução seria esta aqui demonstrada, mas por não saber exactamente qual a estrutura da tua tabela, me basearei nos detalhes fornecidos nos comentários. Apesar de esta a usar uma tabela diferente, o exemplo é muitíssimo simples. O único problema que terias, seria talvez o `slug` que é basicamente o título do artigo, mas com alguns arranjos, para isso tem [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867222/seo-friendly-urls-and-querying-a-database-php), e isto [aqui](http://www.visualscope.com/seo-friendly-urls.html).

***config.php***

```
<?php

// configuracao (nao importante)
$config = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host'=> 'localhost',
        'usr' => 'root',
        'pwd' => '',
        'db'  => 'nuwie'
    ),
    'site' => array(
        'nome' => 'Site sem Nome',
        'inicio' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])
    )
);

// agilizar a busca dos valores da configuração (nao importante) 
function conf($nome){
    $p = preg_split('/[\s-@]/', $nome);
    global $config;
    foreach($config as $nome => $valor){
        if($nome === $p[0] && array_key_exists($p[1], $valor)){
            return $config[$nome][$p[1]];
        }
    }
    return false;
}



// conexao
$mysqli = new  mysqli(conf('mysql-host'), conf('mysql-usr'), conf('mysql-pwd'), conf('mysql-db'));

if($mysqli->errno){
    die('Erro ao conectar banco de dados');
}

// buscar todos os artigos
function buscarArtigos($tabela){
    global $mysqli;
    $resultados = array();
    if($stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,titulo,seo_url FROM {$tabela}")){
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            while($rs = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
                array_push($resultados, $rs);
            }
            return $resultados;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// buscar um artigo pela sua ID
function buscarArtigo($id, $tabela){
    global $mysqli;
    if($stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM {$tabela} WHERE id = {$id}")){
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            return $stmt->fetch_assoc();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// reajustar os titulos para que se adequem a url
// retirada de: http://www.visualscope.com/seo-friendly-urls.html
function friendly_seo_string($vp_string){

    $vp_string = trim($vp_string);

    $vp_string = html_entity_decode($vp_string);

    $vp_string = strip_tags($vp_string);

    $vp_string = strtolower($vp_string);

    $vp_string = preg_replace('~[^ a-z0-9_.]~', ' ', $vp_string);

    $vp_string = preg_replace('~ ~', '-', $vp_string);

    $vp_string = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $vp_string);

    return $vp_string;
}
```

Este ficheiro aqui, contém basicamente as duas únicas funções que precisarias para fazer a ideia funcionar ***buscarArtigos*** e ***buscarArtigo***, o que está aí a mais *(nada importante)* criei no calor do momento já que eram simples com excepção da última que pode vir a ser útil e não é de minha autoria. A função ***friendly_seo_string*** é só necessária quando quiseres criar um artigo novo, por exemplo:

- Quando crias um artigo novo, na tabela do banco de dados para os campos `titulo` e `conteudo` podes usar respectivamente o titulo desejado e o conteúdo, o mesmo aplica-se para o campo `adicionado`, mas para o campo `seo_url` teria de ser o retorno dessa função passando o título usado como argumento *friendly_seo_string(titulo_usado_no_artigo)*. Ou se preferires podes sempre escrever a tua própria função, para que faça a mesma coisa.

***.htaccess***

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^artigos/[0-9]\/(.*)$ ver_artigo.php?artigo=$0
```

Para este exemplo, não precisarias de muito no ficheiro *.htaccess*, apenas estas duas linhas seriam suficientes, ou podes ainda verificar se o módulo `rewrite` se encontra habilitado antes de activá-lo.

***tabela SQL***

```
CREATE TABLE `artigos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `titulo` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `conteudo` text NOT NULL,
  `seo_url` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `adicionado` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

***index.php***

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

print "<a href=\"" .  conf('site-inicio') ."\"><h1>" . conf('site-nome') . "</h1></a>";

// - inicio do conteudo
if(($artigos = buscarArtigos('artigos')) != false){
    foreach($artigos as $artigo){
        print "<div id=\"artigo\">";
        print  "<a href=\"artigos/{$artigo['id']}/{$artigo['seo_url']}\" target=\"_blank\"><h4>{$artigo['titulo']}</h4></a>";
        print "</div>";
    }
} else {
    print "Nenhum artigo encontrado";
}
// - fim do conteudo

?>
```

O ficheiro *index.php*, simplesmente disponibiliza os respectivos títulos e links dos artigos existentes.
Atenção ao link do artigo:

```
print  "<a href=\"artigos/{$artigo['id']}/{$artigo['seo_url']}\" target=\"_blank\"><h4>{$artigo['titulo']}</h4></a>";
```

NA `url` que armazenas, para artigos, deve antes preceder `artigos` no início do *href*.

***ver_artigo.php***

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

if(isset($_GET['artigo'])){
    $artigo_id = explode('/', $_GET['artigo']);

    if(($artigo = buscarArtigo($artigo_id[0], 'artigos')) != false){
        print "<div id=\"artigo\">";
        print "<h2>{$artigo['titulo']}</h2>";
        print $artigo['conteudo'];
        print "</div>";
    } else {
        print "Artigo não encontrado";
    }

    print "<p><a href=\"" .  conf('site-inicio') ."\">voltar</a></p>";

} else {
    print "<h1>Erro</h1>";
}

?>
```

Esta parte, seria o equivalente da tua página *visualizar.pph*. Busca os detalhes desse artigo usando a sua `id` e retorna-os, caso não encontrar o artigo, disponibiliza uma mensagem a dizer que não encontrou o artigo.

Nesse caso, a tua `url` ficaria nesse formato semelhante ao do ptSO:

> www.nomedomeusite.com/artigos/id/titulo-do-artigo

Para o formato:

> www.nomedomeusite.com/empresas/qualquer-empresa

Teria de se fazer corresponder o próprio `slug` em vez da `id` na página que mostra os detalhes do item seleccionado.

> ps.: trabalhei a ideia, mas não dei a mínima para o factor segurança, por isso, recomendo antes, que pesquises principalmente sobre o *.htaccess*, e claro, podes sempre adaptar ou até mesmo , melhorar o código para que funcione com maior aproximação ao que pretendes. Se ainda houver dúvidas, deixe-as nos comentários, e boa sorte.

## Leitura Recomendada

Apache

- [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
- [options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options)
- [htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 1):

O que você busca é uma [Front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller).

Para tal solução no PHP você precisa de algo um tanto mais elaborado, recomendo usar um framework como Symfony ou derivados.
Caso insista em fazer por conta.

O .htaccess para redirecionar o conteudo para o seu visualizar.php mantendo a sua URI como **/**. mas isso é apenas uma parte.

```
#.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 #Sua front controller
 DirectoryIndex visualizar.php
 # Desabilita MultiViews,assim quando "/visualizar"
 #   ele vai resolver internamente para "/visualizar.php/visualizar".
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
 </IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On


    # Define um header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION, o apache se encarrega disso.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    #redirecionamento inicial caso tente entrar /visualizar.php joga para /.
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^visualizar\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Se existir o arquivo ele permanece disponivel.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Redireciona o restante para a front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/visualizar.php [L]
</IfModule>

#saida para quando o mod_rewrite não esta disponivel
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /visualizar.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

No PHP você pode pegar a URI com `$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Caso o seu sistema tenha muitas rotas, sugiro utilizar uma biblioteca pronta como a [FastRoute do nikic](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute). tem uma postagem dele explicando com mais detalhes no repositório.

Agora para as rotas dinâmicas, essas que você busca no banco. caso o acesso seja grande e/ou a query muito cara para seu sistema. Elabore um cache. mas ai seria algo muito mais especifico, onde recomendaria você usar um framwork

Comment: Desculpa, por inexperiência nisso, não entendi como esse seu código pode arrumar minha URL do jeito que eu quero, Não vi nenhuma chamada para meu id e nem nenhuma forma em que tu pegou o nome da empresa

Comment: Então,  veja o conteúdo de $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; no seu sistema.
A ideia de front controller é igual um roteador, ele recebe todas as `requests` do sistema e com base na `URI` que seria o final da sua `URL`  a parte incluindo a primeira `/` decide qual controller acionar.. podendo essas controller serem funções, classes ou mesmo seus `.php` . sendo algo muito especifico de sua implementação

Comment: E após eu ver o conteúdo dessa `request`, o que eu faço?

Comment: E sobre esse Symfony que tu mencionou, é uma solução mais facil? Como usar ele?

Comment: O symfony é um framework, considero mais fácil. Isso é para mim, desconhecendo seu conhecimento não sei dizer, case você seja da área ou queria entrar recomendo começar a usar logo um framework e aprender design pattern, leia o GoF