# Criar link de perfil estilo facebook

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olá, gostaria de saber como fazer para aparecer no link dos perfis de cliente do meu projeto estilo link do facebook (facebook.com/nome_do_perfil). Pois não consigo colocar sem ser por get (site.com/perfil.php?per=nome_do_perfil), (sendo "?per=" a variável do nome dos perfis), gostaria de fazer um esquema que tirasse esse "perfil.php?per=" para por direto. Obrigado!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como posso simplificar os URLs para um site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326/como-posso-simplificar-os-urls-para-um-site)

Comment: A maneira mais fácil e a que eu uso é um `RewriteRule` com o .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer uma URL assim, pode-se utilizar um padrão de projeto chamado Front Controller, onde todas as requisições do seu site serão administradas pelo **index.php**

Exemplo de como ficam as URLs com front-controller:

```
seusite.com/categorias
seusite.com/categoria/1
seusite.com/categoria/create
```

Entendendo o conceito e aplicando ao seu projeto ficaria assim. Quando uma requisição bater no seu index.php (Exemplo: seusite.com/NomeDoPerfil ) o seu index vai procurar no seu banco de dados se existe esse username. Se se existir ele traz a view com as informações do usuário.

É bem simples montar um Front Controller em um projeto de PHP puro, mas uma alternativa é trabalhar com um framework PHP que já tem em seu core esse padrão de projeto e muitos outros que facilitam o desenvolvimento de aplicações, sempre seguindo as melhores praticas. Vou deixar o link de alguns caso tenha interesse.

- [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) (Atualmente o mais popular)
- [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/)
- [Symfony](https://symfony.com/)

Abraços !